# Finally block is invoked before awaiting promise resolution in try block

Tags: javascript, promise

My code looks something like this:

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const results = await heavyCalculation();
    saveResultsToFiles(results);
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit(0);
  }
})();

const saveResultsToFiles = (results) => {
  results.forEach(result => {
    (async () => await saveResultFile(result));
  })
}

const saveResultFile = (result) => {
  return promiseToPreprocess(result)
    .then(processedResult => saveToFile(processedResult))
}

const promiseToPreprocess = async (result) => {
  // this function returns a promise to preprocess the data
}

const saveToFile = (data) => {
  // this function synchronously saves data to a file
}
```

I thought this code would

1. perform calculations
2. wait for each piece of the results to be preprocessed and saved to a file
3. then exit

The first step works, as the program seems to await the heavy calculation results. However, it appears the finally clause is entered before the promise within the forEach-loop is resolved, causing the program to exit early. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't know anything about `async` functions. The functions return promises but `.forEach()` always ignores return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. Your `forEach` loop in `saveResultsToFiles` does not return anything so you have no way to make other parts of your code "wait" for each item's promise to resolve.
2. `saveResultFile` returns a promise but this promise is not `await`ed in your `try` block.

The result of both of these issues is that the `try` block only "starts" the process of saving to files but doesn't wait for it to finish before yieling to the `finally` block.

Here are solutions you could try.

1. You need to be able to `await` each of the `saveResultFile` calls and for that you need to access the array of promises instanciated in `saveResultsToFiles`. With `.map` you will actually get an array of results (as opposed to `.forEach`):

```
const saveResultsToFiles = (results) => {
  return results.map(result => saveResultFile(result));
}
```

2. Now that `saveResultsToFiles` actually returns an array of promises, you should `await` all of them before proceeding. This is exactly what `Promise.all` is for:

```
try {
    const results = await heavyCalculation();
    await Promise.all(saveResultsToFiles(results));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realise it was the forEach function that caused the issue. As a slight tweak to your solution, I used `return Promise.all(results.map(...` and then simply `await saveResultsToFiles` as it feels like it is more logical to return one promise than an array of promises.

Comment: So it appears it din't work entirely. The finally block is still called before the `.then` function of `saveResultFile`, meaning the file is not actually saved. How can I force the promise to be awaited along with the then clause before moving on to the finally block?

Comment: For the `.then` to be called I needed to change the function within `.map` to `async result => await saveResultFile(result)`, although I don't understand why.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén Are you sure `saveToFile` returns a promise?

Comment: ah, that's it. It didn't.

Answer (score -1):

You are not awaiting `saveResultsToFiles(results);`

Try:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const results = await heavyCalculation();
    saveResultsToFiles(results);
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit(0);
  }
})();

const saveResultsToFiles = async (results) => {
  results.forEach(result => {
    await saveResultFile(result);
  })
}

const saveResultFile = (result) => {
  return promiseToPreprocess(result)
    .then(processedResult => saveToFile(processedResult))
}

const promiseToPreprocess = async (result) => {
  // this function returns a promise to preprocess the data
}

const saveToFile = (data) => {
  // this function synchronously saves data to a file
}
```

Comment: *"SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators"*